# 'return' outside function (making text gradient)

Tags: python

line 18
i'm making a text gradient and cant seem to get this right. here's my code.
what the h*** is wrong with the indention here?

```
import math
gradient = ('FF24E9', 'F026EC', 'E128F0', 'D22AF3', 'C32CF7', 'A530FE', '8F3EFE', '7A4CFE', '655AFE', '5068FE', '3B76FE')
def gradientmadness(text):
    leng = len(text)
output = ''
if leng < 11:
    for i in range(0, leng):
        output += '<c=#%s>' % gradient[i]
for i in range(0, leng):
    output += text[i] + '</c>'
else :
    output += '<c=#'
output += '><c=#'.join(gradient)
output += '>'
size = int(math.ceil(leng / 11.0))
for i in range(1, 11 + 1):
    output += text[(i - 1) * size: i * size] + '</c>'
return output
gradientmadness.command = "gradient1"
```

Comment: The formatting is fairly simple once you've learned it.  Paste the code into the question; highlight it; hit Ctrl-k.  Voila: code.

Comment: The problem is just what the error said: you have a `return` outside of a function.  How do you fix it?  That depends on your purpose.

Comment: In python, indentation matters. The way your code is written, `gradientmadness` only has 1 line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with correct formatting :

```
import math


gradient = ('FF24E9', 'F026EC', 'E128F0', 'D22AF3', 'C32CF7', 'A530FE', '8F3EFE', '7A4CFE', '655AFE', '5068FE', '3B76FE')
def gradientmadness(text):
    leng = len(text)
    output = ''
    if leng < 11:
        for i in range(0, leng):
            output += '<c=#%s>' % gradient[i]
        for i in range(0, leng):
            output += text[i] + '</c>'
    else :
        output += '<c=#'

    output += '><c=#'.join(gradient)
    output += '>'
    size = int(math.ceil(leng / 11.0))

    for i in range(1, 11 + 1):
        output += text[(i - 1) * size: i * size] + '</c>'
    return output


gradientmadness.command = "gradient1"
```

Comment: the indentation is wrong in the two for's inside if and the indentation of return statement was also wrong.